# Office 365 rest api - Search files

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm using office 365 rest api's(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations) to list the files. But dont find a api to search files? Is search supported in office 365 api's?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article that explains Search API available for SharePoint:

SharePoint Search REST API overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876(v=office.15).aspx

I hope that is what you were looking for!